How to use my own optical endpoint for an ISP?
I would like to use my own device in my home to connect to the optical line from the ISP.
I have a TP-Link MC200CM optical to ethernet converter, which in turn should connect to an GL-X3000C16
The ISP's device currently at my end is an XPON ONU 8247R5.
The plug from the wall that goes into the ISP device seems to fit the ethernet converter fine.
However, my ISP is telling me they are not compatible, and that my end needs the following features. They refuse to elaborate further:

Must be compatible OLT ZTE C320.
Possible to configure PPPoE.
Optical port SC/APC.

I did not try the setup yet, but I would like to understand exactly what are the potential issues here.
The only thing that I can see is that somehow the optical signal protocol somehow is different, and I need a different converter device.
Any insight or sources to read to introduce and clarify the problem domain would be appreciated.

You are connected to a passive optical network (PON). It doesn't use 1000BASE-SX.


Must be compatible OLT ZTE C320

That (i.e. the specification sheets of both the ZTE C320 and the MC200CM) already provides the necessary information: the device on the other end of your fiber is a GPON OLT, whereas your TP-Link is not a GPON endpoint at all.
Your MC200CM is specifically a fiber-Ethernet endpoint; it expects the fiber variant of Gigabit Ethernet (in terms of signalling and framing), i.e. it is a 1000BASE-SX to 1000BASE-T converter for a symmetric, point-to-point connection.
Your ISP doesn't use that; it uses GPON, a protocol designed for 'passive' optical networks with multiple nodes attached to the same transmitter (somewhat like the optical equivalent of DOCSIS over TV cable). GPON is highly asymmetric, as one endpoint at the OLT connects to multiple ONUs via splitters.
On top of that, the MC200CM is for multi-mode fiber, which adds several incompatibilities on its own.
This adds up to many differences that make the two completely incompatible in the end:

The connector is not actually the same. GPON connections use an SC/APC connector (green), in which the tip of the fiber is polished at an angle to reduce signal reflections, unlike SC/UPC (blue) used for most Ethernet connections.
If you plug an SC/APC cord into a SC/UPC socket, at best there will be a small triangular gap between the surfaces, resulting in some loss of signal power; at worst it might even damage both surfaces.

The fiber type is incompatible. GPON is delivered over single-mode fiber, while the MC200CM has multi-mode optics. It can receive the signal to an extent, but there are massive losses when transmitting a MM signal through a SM fiber (it's like shining a large torch through a pinhole).
Although that's moot because your MC200CM (like most multi-mode equipment) has separate 'transmit' and 'receive' ports, so connecting the ISP fiber to the 'receive' port means you'll only be transmitting into air.
(Single-mode Ethernet can be implemented either way, e.g. compare MC210CS which uses separate fibers with TL-FC311B which uses different wavelengths.)

The wavelength (or color, or frequency) used for transmission is not the same. Data over fiber is usually modulated on a specific frequency, much like in radio, and a single fiber can carry multiple frequencies/wavelengths at the same times.
Your MC200CM, being a multi-mode fiber endpoint, receives and transmits at 850nm, whereas your GPON ONU receives at 1490nm and transmits at 1310nm, meaning that they physically cannot consume or generate a compatible signal.
(The last two differences are mostly due to fiber type, as single-mode optical Ethernet equipment also uses wavelengths in the 1310–1550nm range and could optionally receive/transmit over a single fiber – although in any case it would still be incompatible with GPON.)

The data being transmitted is different. Although GPON carries data that is Ethernet compatible, there is a whole additional "link layer" underneath that negotiates with the ISP-side OLT to authenticate itself, agree on an encryption key, arrange on the 'transmit' timeslot, and so on. (Plus some differences "just because" GPON is an ITU-T protocol.)
So what you receive over the ISP's fiber connection is really "Ethernet-in-GPON", a lot like how ADSL used to be Ethernet-over-ATM.
In contrast, an Ethernet media converter like MC200CM just sends the same Ethernet frames exactly as they come.
(Because everything that the OLT transmits is received simultaneously by all ONUs, it has to be encrypted so that e.g. your neighbor won't be able to easily snoop on all DNS packets that you receive. And because GPON has multiple ONUs transmitting back to a single OLT at the same time, at the same wavelength, they are only allowed to transmit at their specific timeslots.)


So in conclusion, look at the spec sheets and make sure you're getting a GPON ONU (ONT) next time. (From what I've heard, if the ISP asks for compatibility with ZTE equipment, it's a safest bet to get a ZTE one as well, as other manufacturers are not always 100% compatible.)

Wow, such a thorough answer. Thank you so much for putting in the effort. The original motivation was to have an open source / libre device on my end, but judging from what you write last that seems to be not a very likely option?

Unlikely for GPON equipment – though ITU-T GPON specs are freely available, but I guess there's not much interest in making such hardware given that it is inherently tied to expensive infrastructure at the ISP side, making it difficult to test. Although I wouldn't really call TP-Link MC200CM an open-source/libre device either...

Yeah, fair enough, I didn't really buy that TP-LInk for this particular scenario, but had it lying around and though maybe try it out since "optical, that must fit" - like a moron. Again, many thanks, lots of futile hours potentially spared there.
